# Cloning AutoID into another field in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created the following table in SQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SimpleTable](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [OtherField] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Position] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SimpleTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

When a new record gets inserted I want to update the Position field with the value from the IDENTITY column, the main idea is that the record should be positioned at the end, but the user will be able to change that position later on.

I thought about creating a Trigger and update the position field after insert, however I will have a lot of these tables and I really want to try to stay away from triggers if I can.

Does anyone have a more elegant solution?

Comment: Trigger does seem like the most appropriate solution for this - unless you can live with updating that `Position` column only e.g. every hour; then you could have a SQL job that would just update those rows that don't have a value just yet...

Comment: I could, but I dont think its necessary, by his message he always want to have the position equals the ID

Answer (score 1):

This should work inside a stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertIntoSimpleTable]
    @Name varchar(50)
,   @OtherField varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Id INT;

    --- Do your insert here.
    INSERT INTO SimpleTable (Name, OtherField)
    SELECT @Name, @OtherField
    ;

    SELECT @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    UPDATE SimpleTable SET Position = @Id WHERE Id = @Id;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are not that bad. 
Greco’s solution is good but I’m posting how a trigger solution would be in case you are not inserting data to your tables through procedures

```
create trigger TR_SetDefaultValue
on [SimpleTable]
after insert 
as
begin
   UPDATE [SimpleTable] 
   SET [Position] = I.[ID]
   FROM INSERTED AS I
   WHERE [SimpleTable].ID=I.ID
end
```

Comment: You may want to check that the [Position] column was not explictly set on the insert prior to updating it in the trigger.