# Use autogenerated column to populate another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I use an auto-generated column to populate another column during an `INSERT` statement?

Long story short: we are reusing a database table and an related ASP page to display completely different data than was originally intended.

I have a table similar in structure to the following. It's structure is out of my control.

```
ID       int          NON-NULL, IDENTITY(1,1)
OrderNo  varchar(50)  NON-NULL, UNIQUE
More     ...
```

The table has been repurposed and we are not using the `OrderNo` column. However, it's `NON-NULL` and `UNIQUE`. As dummy data, I want to populate it with the row's `ID` column.

I have the following SQL so far, but can't work out how to use the row's generated `ID`.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (OrderNo, More)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
VALUES (CAST(ID AS varchar(50)))
```

This just gives:

> *Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>
>   Invalid column name 'ID'.*

Comment: why these solutions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484182/cloning-autoid-into-another-field-in-sql-server?rq=1) did not work for you

Comment: @cha because my searches didn't reveal those options.  Thanks!

Comment: why in one table require columns with same data?

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko, that's answered in the question.  I'm respurposing a table, but I can't change the table structure.  I don't want to use the field but it's NON-NULL UNIQUE, so I must.  To ensure unique data, I want to copy the ID column which is guaranteed unique.   But what you say makes me realise why there isn't a straightforward solution to begin with.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using the OUTPUT clause. Unfortunately, you won't be able to do it in a single statement.

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
   ID      int         not null identity(1,1),
   OrderNo varchar(50) not null unique
)

CREATE TABLE #NewIDs ( ID int )

INSERT Orders (OrderNo)
   OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO #NewIDs
SELECT 12345

UPDATE o
   SET o.OrderNo = i.ID
FROM Orders o
JOIN #NewIDs i
   ON i.ID = o.ID

SELECT * FROM Orders
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be:

```
create trigger YourTable_Trigger
on YourTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
as begin

   INSERT INTO YourTable (OrderNo, AnotherField)
   SELECT 0, AnotherField FROM Inserted

   UPDATE YourTable SET OrderNo = SCOPE_IDENTITY() WHERE ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
end;
```

And here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0aa35/1).

Good luck.

Comment: why use INSTEAD OF INSERT? And what if they add a new column called NewField? Will they be required to fix the trigger as well?